# What is the time complexity of finding the rank of a square matrix?

Tags: matrix, time-complexity, linear-algebra

I need to find the number of linearly independent columns in a square n*n matrix. What is the time complexity of this operation?

Comment: I think the difficulty here is not so much the time complexity as the numerical stability of the algorithm, If you are working in floating point then it is highly likely that simple algorithms will, due to the approximate nature of floating point arithmetic, report a matrix as having full rank when it doesn't. The set of full rank matrices is dense in the set of matrices -- given any matrix there is a full rank matrix arbitrarily close to it. You might want to read up on 'rank revealing qr'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular Gauss elimination is `O(n^3)`.
There are other potential solutions (e.g. iteratives or ones for sparse matrices) but they usually don't have a straightforward complexity.